# Running python script in Laravel with symfony gives error "Python is not recogninzed as interal or external command"

Tags: python, php, laravel, symfony

I am trying to execute a python script in Laravel using Symfony.

[image: Error]

I got this error. I have tried :

```
$process = new Process(['...'], null, ['ENV_VAR_NAME' => 'value']);
```

The `ENV_VAR_NAME` value is set to my python 39 directory.

I'm on windows. Can anybody help me with this?

I've tried this,

```
$process = new Process(['python', 'top_movies.py'],null,['ENV_VAR_NAME' => 'C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39']);        $process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
     throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
        
$ar = $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: That message normally means the executable cannot be found. Did you put your python directory on the windows PATH

Comment: Can you please show the code that actually tries to execute python?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did put my python directory on windows path. The script runs with my command prompt.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://i.imgur.com/pk9JfLp.png. I tried this

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67165844/edit) to include the code as text, not an image.

Comment: I haven't used this component, but I'm quite sure that `ENV_VAR_NAME` is just an example name in their docs, which you should replace with the name of the actual environment variable you want to set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson. I added it as text

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What should I actually write? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Instead of passing it as an env. variable, have you tried to simply write the full path directly: `new Process(['C:\path\to\Python39\python', 'top_movies.py'], ....)`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok. I tried this, $process = new Process(['C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python', 'top_movies.py']); Now I get an error saying Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: D:\N\MovieRSystem\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized

Comment: @MagnusEriksson. I had it working on my linux. This only ocurred when I migrated from linux to windows. It works on my cmd though